# Hide the Main Form in a Delphi 2009 Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl

The following code works fine in Delphi 7. However, in Delphi 2009 the form does remain hidden but the button on the taskbar is now appearing.

```
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW );
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
```

The above code is called in the FormCreate method.

Comment: The form does NOT remain hidden for me in D2007 nor D2009 with your exact code.
Which seems what you want for whatever reason if you put this:  
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW); 
Seemed to me you wanted to SHOW it not HIDE it.
Please update and precise your question as it appears you want the opposite..

Comment: The above code is used to remove the form button from the taskbar pre 2009. The goal is just to get the form's taskbar button to stop appearing. I have writtin a small test app and that code seems to work fine. However, in this particular instance it seems as the it is the Applications hidden form.

Comment: Deleted my answer, since it didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the reason we were seeing the Application window on the taskbar was a simple setting similar to stukelly's answer but not quite.

To get the main form to appear on the task bar and hide the application menu you apply:

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.ShowMainForm := False;
```

No code behind the form create or anything required.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution back on stack overflow.  I thought you wanted to hide the taskbar button and the main form.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have code in FormActivate(). The form never shows so the FormActivate() never gets called.

Comment: @TheSteven that makes complete sense, the form should never become active...it's hidden. If you have code in `FormActivate` for a hidden form then it's obviously the wrong place for it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the [ShowMainForm](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_ShowMainForm.html) and [MainFormOnTaskBar](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_MainFormOnTaskBar.html) properties to False before the form is created.

Open your project source and set **MainFormOnTaskBar** and **ShowMainForm** to False, before the form is created.

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := false;
Application.ShowMainForm := false;
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

Then on your main form add the following code to the **FormActivate** and **FormShow** events.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 // hide taskbar button
 ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 // hide taskbar button
 ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

I have tested with Dephi 2007 and 2009.  Additional information is available [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/hide_taskbutton.htm).