# Delphi hide the form, not hide the application icon on taskbar

Tags: delphi

I use the following code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.visible := false;
  Form2.show;
end;
```

Yes, the form1 got hidden and the form2 show up. But why the application icon in the taskbar also got hidden....

I use the following codes and still can not show the icon on the taskbar, while hide the form1.

```
      visible := false;
{
      enable := false;
      Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
      ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_SHOW);
      SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
}
```

How to keep the application icon on the taskbar while I want to hide the form ?

I want to do it in the unit files , not the DPR file.

The Files that I want to do keep the system taskbar are at : http://sidhiciang.com/myfiles/ShowHideForms.rar

```
Unit1.pas
  If Form1.btShowForm2Click() , then 
    Hide Form1 and Show Form2 ( actHideForm1execute(self)).
  If Form1.btCloseForm1Click(), then 
    Close the application

Unit2.pas
  If  Form2.btShowForm3Click(), then 
    Hide Form2 and Show Form3 ( actHideForm2execute(self)).
  If Form2.btCloseForm2Click(), then 
    Show the Form1 and Form2.close (actShowForm1execute(self))

Unit3.pas
  If btCloseFrom3Click(), then
    Show Form2 and Close Form3
```

In all of the Unit1 / Unit2 / Unit3, Keep the application icon on taskbar available. Because if I use .visible := false, the system taskbar also become hidden.

PS: I use Delphi 2010 and running on Windows XP and 7 Enviorment.

Comment: Only visible top level windows show on the taskbar. You put the main form on the taskbar, and so when you hide it, it is removed from taskbar. I should say that setting MainFormOnTaskbar to False should be sufficient. That will use the Application window as the taskbar window.

Comment: It would help if you posted real code. For instance, when you said enable := False, there is no enable property. It would also help if you made it clear when the code runs. At startup only, or at a point where the main form is already showing.

Comment: Read my comment closely. You want to do this at startup only? Or at a point where the main for is already showing. If you can just make the question clear, you'll get an answer.

Comment: OK, I add the rar files (the source code). I want hide the form1 that is already showing, so when I hit the button, it will hide the form1 and show the form2, while keep the application icon on taskbar available.

Comment: I cannot look at this until tomorrow, but why don't you just minimize the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, now that it is clear what you want, first a couple of things:

- The first Form created is automatically the MainForm,
- An application cannot without a MainForm; when the MainForm closes, the application closes, whatever other forms are shown,
- You can hide the MainForm,
- By default (in older Delphi versions anyway) the application's window is shown on the taskbar (`Application.MainFormOnTaskbar = False`). As long as the application is active, and as long as there is at least one form showing, this icon/window is shown in the taskbar.
- When `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar = True`, then the icon/window of the MainForm is shown in the taskbar. When the MainForm is hiden, the icon dissapears. Showing another form does not result in another taskbar icon/window, so there is no icon at all then.

So, it is clear you need to set `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False` in the project file.

Furthermore, the following combination of methods seems to work as you want:

**Unit1/Form1/MainForm:**

```
procedure TForm1.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.OpenForm2ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm2.Create(Self).Show;
  Hide;
end;
```

**Unit2/Form2:**

```
procedure TForm2.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  TForm(Owner).Show;
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TForm2.OpenForm3ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm3.Create(Self).Show;
  Hide;
end;
```

**Unit3/Form3:**

```
procedure TForm3.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  TForm(Owner).Show;
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Note that the caption of the taskbar button remains the same during these changes. If you want to synchronize that with the caption of the form being shown, set `Application.Title`.

Comment: Great it works  :) the key is on Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False ... I was mistaken with True... :P

Comment: anyway how can I change the .tag value for TForm(Owner).Show; ?

Comment: Add a variable for the form? That code of mine is just a quick and dirty example which you of course can modify to your needs.

Comment: Yes, change the Form1.tag when closing the Form2. Should I use " TForm(Owner).Tag := 9; " OR " Form1.Tag := 9; " OR any other method ?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you want but I think you are trying to ask a new question here. Please ask a new question, then we all can respond/help.

Answer (score 5):

You may toggle between the *handles* shown on the taskbar.
Show the application on hiding and the form on showing.

```
procedure TForm1.HideIt;
begin
  Visible := false;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := false;
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_SHOW);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowIt;
begin
  Visible := true;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := true;
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_Hide);
end;

// overrride CreateParams:  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := true;
end;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need WS_EX_APPWINDOW?

Comment: There should be no need for *forcing* here. Isn't this a top level unowned window? In other words, isn't Params.WndParent equal to 0.

Comment: OK, thinking about this more. The window will be owned by the application window if and only if the application window is the taskbar window.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Form1` being the main Form and `Form1.Hide` doing everything you want, except that the taskbar button should remain visible, then what you really want to do is minimize the application:

```
Application.Minimize;
```

---

Otherwise, you probably are looking for [Hide the Main Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/796766/757830).

Comment: What about if I add the button to show the Form2 ? your code work like what I wanted, only if I work with one form. When I work with with more than one form, I will the minimize the whole form... how to minimize or hide the other forms, while keep the latest form visible ?

Comment: @SidhiCiang I really wish that you would edit the question as I asked in my second comment to the question. I feel that for sure we could give you the answer you need if you could tell us more about the context.